# how to combine values from object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've array like this

```
const data=[ {name:aa, status:[key:0, value: true] },
         {name:ee, status:[key:1, value: true] },
         {name:ii, status:[key:1, value: true] },
       ]
```

I want to convert it into like this

```
const data=[aa, ee, ii]
```

P.S. thank you.

---

tried like this

data.map(({ status, ...data }) =>  Object.values(data).concat);

Comment: `status:[key:0, value: true]` this is not valid. arrays have no keys in literal notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of objects, you need to take `name` from the object probably by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and map this value.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: 'aa', status: { key: 0, value: true } }, { name: 'ee', status: { key: 1, value: true } }, { name: 'ii', status: { key: 1, value: true } }],
    result = data.map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(result);
```